# vlan for segmentation, same subnet one dhcp server

Tags: router, switch, vlan, dhcp-server

I do not know if this is the correct setup.

I need to isolate three ports on three different switches from the other ports (update: so they are separated from the others and also have access to the internet). I guess VLAN is the way to go... But I do not need a specific IP-range for the two VLANs. It is fine if they share DHCP-server.

Is this possible? Two VLANS created on the switches just to segment (update: ment as separate) the ports. And no VLAN creation on the router/DHCP-server since it is all just one big LAN after all?

I have tried with no luck. So I've started to expect that I need another approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to isolate three ports on three different switches from the other ports.

So you want to have three ports that can talk to ... nobody? If they actually should be able to talk to each other, put them in the same VLAN and tag the uplinking ports.

> I guess VLAN is the way to go...

Most definately, yes.

> But I do not need a specifik IP-range for the to VLANs.

VLANs separate traffic in layer 2, IP-Adresses are layer 3. So, no, you don't *need* separate IP-Ranges. Most certainly most admins will *recommend* it, its technically not *needed*.

> It is fine if they share DHCP-server.

If the port is **isolated** in it's own VLAN, nothing is shared with nobody. Think of it as a separate switch. If you need a DHCP, you need to put one in. If they should be able to talk to anything else, tag/untag it that way.

> Two VLANS created on the switches just to segment the ports.

Yes, that's what VLANs are made for, segmentation and (sometimes) isolation. A segment is a completely independent construct - think of it as a virtual switch which has ports on other switches.

> no VLAN creation on the router/DHCP-server since it is all just one big LAN afterall?

No, every VLAN is it's own completely separated network. If you need routers or DHCPs in them, you need to put them in. You can use multiple interfaces on your hosts, connect the networks through a router/firewall with multiple interfaces or tagged ports or (in many cases) let the switch do the routing work. DHCP can also be relayed through a ip helper (dhcp relay agent). Segmentation is almost the same as separation. Two segments, two servers.

> I have tried with no luck. So start to expect that I need another aproach.

It's hard to imagine what you have tried exactly, when you are not telling us.

Here is what I would do, if I hat to connect three ports on three different switches, which should be able to talk to each other, asuming SwitchZ connects them, using VLAN100 as "isolation" network and VLAN 1 as default:

SwitchA to SwitchC:

```
SwitchA - All ports UNTAGGED VLAN 1
SwitchA - Port1 UNTAGGED VLAN 100 <-- the 'isolation' port. Stuff you stick in here will get into VLAN100. "UNTAGGED" (HPE/Baracuda) is the same as "ACCESS" (Cisco).
SwitchA - Port24 TAGGED VLAN 100 and UNTAGGED 1 <-- The Uplink Port. It should transport VLAN 100 ("tagged") and defaulkt to 1.
```

SwitchZ (which connects the uplinks)

```
SwitchA - All ports UNTAGGED VLAN 1
SwitchA - Port1-3 TAGGED VLAN 100 <-- the uplinks from the SwitchesA-C. Should transport VLAN100 and default to 1.
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your post. Spot on with the "talk to... nobody". Both VLAN's need access to the DHCP-router. I update the question with this calrification.

Comment: Great answers, but one omission: It is possible to use the same DHCP server, as long as you use some sort of dhcp relay agent (typically on the router).  ... that being said, I do not think this is a great situation to implement one.

Comment: Depends on your infrastructure; as long as you use different subnets per vlan one single dhcp can be a good choice. A *very* bad one if using the same adresses, though. And: if you want to use the same router for all vlans, the vlans need to be routed there. Or the router need different interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hosts on the two VLANs can use one DHCP server, but they will need different scopes.  You need a separate IP subnet for each VLAN.  You can have the same subnet span across two different VLANs.